# Why am I seeing this getJSON error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the [rottentomatoes movie API](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/json/v10/examples) with [twitter's bootstrap typeahead plugin](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) but I keep getting the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=MY_API_KEY&page_limit=5&q=t&format=jsonp. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

My code looks like this:

```
    var autocomplete = $('#searchinput').typeahead()
    .on('keyup', function(ev){

        ev.stopPropagation();
        ev.preventDefault();

        //filter out up/down, tab, enter, and escape keys
        if( $.inArray(ev.keyCode,[40,38,9,13,27]) === -1 ){

            var self = $(this);

            //set typeahead source to empty
            self.data('typeahead').source = [];

            //active used so we aren't triggering duplicate keyup events
            if( !self.data('active') && self.val().length > 0){

                self.data('active', true);

                $.getJSON("http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=API_KEY_REMOVED&page_limit=5",{
                    q: $(this).val()
                }, function(data) {


                    //set this to true when your callback executes
                    self.data('active',true);

                    //Filter out your own parameters. Populate them into an array, since this is what typeahead's source requires
                    var arr = [],
                        i=data.movies.length;
                    while(i--){
                        arr[i] = data.movies[i].title
                    }

                    //set your results into the typehead's source 
                    self.data('typeahead').source = arr;

                    //trigger keyup on the typeahead to make it search
                    self.trigger('keyup');

                    //All done, set to false to prepare for the next remote query.
                    self.data('active', false);

                });

            }
        }
    });
```

Any idea what is causing this error?

Comment: Likely relevant: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a security concern cross browser calls are not allowed see <sup>[**CORS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)</sup>, either you will have to create a proxy, have your proxy call the cross domain and return you the results, or if the server at the other domain supports you can use [**jsonp**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/)

Comment: Looks like they support jsonp.  Can I simply add that format to my getJSON query?

Comment: @Paul  try putting `?callback=?` at the end of your url it should work if jsonp is supported

Comment: `$.getJSON("http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=API_KEY_REMOVED&page_limit=5?callback=?",{
`

Comment: first comment by Paul suggests that it is supported, did you try the code in third comment... i really have a bad memory dont remember now...

Comment: Attempting to insert ?callback=? gives me a `GET 403 (Forbidden)` result in the console.

Comment: Adding `callback=?` at the end works! http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/forum/read/162308

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use invalid URL that violate the same origin policy.

You have to send AJAX request to the same `domain`.
Is this the real url you want, or you just copied it from their website?!

`Same origin policy` on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy):

> In computing, the same origin policy is an important security concept for a number of browser-side programming languages, such as JavaScript. The policy permits scripts running on pages originating from the same site to access each other's methods and properties with no specific restrictions, but prevents access to most methods and properties across pages on different sites.
>   ...

[Workarounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Workarounds)

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this error because Ajax request(basically xhrXML) doesn't allow cross domain communication. If you really want to access resources from other domain then you can use hidden iframe for fetching content from other domain.It's really simple and have been used even before ajax is introduced.

For more information you can read this http://www.yaldex.com/ajax-tutorial-4/BBL0020.html
(Please go through iframe section only)

But I am alerting you that certain sites doesn't allow you to show there content inside iframe for example twitter. They have X-Frame-Option in their header which prevents displaying their pages inside a iframe. So first check header of you resource which you are trying to fetch using iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for JSONP and Cross-Domain requests using [typeahead 0.9.1](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js)

```
$('input.typeahead').typeahead [
    remote: {
        url: 'http://remote-server.com/results.json?query=%QUERY&callback=?',
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    },
    minLength: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the answer above returns a 403 forbidden with the rotten tomatoes api,

by changing it to &callback=? rather than ?callback=? it returns the JSON object appropriately on localhost